# WPF Tabcontrol Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, tabcontrol

there is my code

```
     <TabControl x:Name="TabControlSQL" Margin="10,10,10,10" Grid.Row="2" SelectionChanged="TabControlSQL_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeader" DataType="TabItem">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SourceImageTab}" FontSize="20" Foreground="Red"></TextBlock>//binding not work
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="[" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem }, Path=Header}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="]" />
                        <Button Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Grid.Column="2" Height="15" Width="15" Padding="0" Name="btnUnLock" Click="btnUnLock_Click" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding SourceImageTab}" Height="12" ></Image>//binding not work
                        </Button>
                        <Button Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Grid.Column="3" Height="15" Width="15" Name="btnDelete" Padding="0"  Margin="3,0,0,0" Click="btnDelete_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Name}">
                            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="..//Resources/cancel.png" Height="12" ></Image>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.Resources>
        </TabControl>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SourceImageTab}" FontSize="20" Foreground="Red"></TextBlock>//this work
```

why only one binding work? the first and the seconds no, why? maybe the problem is tabcontrol binding? i also have added in Window.Inizialized {DataContext=this}, thanks

this is the property

```
public string SourceImageTab
    {
        get
        {
            return "..//Resources/locked.png";
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you set `DataContext = this` and this is the `MainWindow` (not the source collection), then `TabControl.ItemsSource` binding won't work too. You must bind it to a collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working with two different scopes: scope of `MainWindow` and scope of `DataTemplate`.

Both scopes have different `DataContext` values:
since you have set `MainWindow.DataContext` to `this`, the `MainWindow.DataContext` is the `MainWindow` itself.
The `DataTemplate.DataContext` is always the targeted data item, which is in your case the current `TabItem`.

Since `SourceImageTab` is defined on `MainWindow`, the binding in the scope of `MainWIndow` works. The binding `Binding SourceImageTab` resolves to the `MainWindow.SourceImageTab` property. But inside the `DataTemplate` the same binding expression resolves to `TabIte.SourceImageTab`, which doesn't exist.

The solution is to adjust the bindings inside the `DataTemplate`. In order to find the `MainWindow` you can use `Binding.RelativeSource`. Also the bindings that are currently having the `TabItem` as source can be simplified to e.g. `{Binding Header}":

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
// TODO::Create a binding source collection which binds to the TabControl
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public ObservableCollection<MyTabDataItem> TabItems { get; set; }
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<TabControl x:Name="TabControlSQL" ItemsSource="{Binding MyTabDataItem}">
  <TabControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeader" DataType="TabItem">
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          ...
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=SourceImageTab}" FontSize="20" Foreground="Red" /> //binding now works

        ...           

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Header}" />

        ...

        <Button>
          <Image Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=SourceImageTab}" /> //binding now works
        </Button>
        ...
        <Button CommandParameter="{Binding Name}">
          <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="..//Resources/cancel.png" Height="12"  />
        </Button>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding SourceImageTab}" FontSize="20" Foreground="Red" /> // this worked before
```

Comment: I am happy I could help.